# Multiple copies of the same form within same page confuses checkbox clicks

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have multiple copies of the same form (called from the same `contact-form.php` file) on the same page (which take different values in hidden inputs depending on how it was called), however when the checkbox label is clicked on in the form at the bottom of the page, it jumps up to the first instance of the form on the page, and checks that checkbox. How can I overcome this?

The form that is included (I am aware I dont have the definitions for the inputs but its very long business logic that is futile for the purpose of this question):

```
<form action="post/send.php" method="post" class="contact-form">
<h2><?php echo $lang['CONTACT_TITLE']; ?></h2>
<h4><?php echo $lang['CONTACT_SUBTITLE']; ?></h4>
<div>
    <label for="first_name"><?php echo $lang['fname']; ?></label>
    <input name="first_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $fn;?>" required>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="last_name"><?php echo $lang['lname']; ?></label>
    <input name="last_name" type="text" value="<?php echo $ln;?>" required>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="email"><?php echo $lang['email_addr']; ?></label>
    <input name="email" type="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" required>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="req_date"><?php echo $lang['CONTACT_DATE']; ?></label>
    <input type="date" name="req_date" max="2030-12-31" value="<?php if(isset($date)) { echo $date;}?>" min="<?php echo $today;?>" required>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="message"><?php echo $lang['ORDER_COMMENT']; ?></label>
    <textarea name="message" required><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message;} ?></textarea>
</div>
<input type="number" name="package" hidden value="<?php if(isset($packageId) && !is_null($packageId)) { echo $packageId;} else { echo $package;}?>">
<input type="number" name="size" hidden value="<?php echo $packageSize; ?>">
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="makeup" name="makeup" <?php if(isset($mkup)) { echo $mkup; }?> value="true"><label for="makeup"><?php echo $lang['MAKEUP_ICON']; ?></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hairdresser" name="hairdresser" <?php if(isset($hd)) {echo $hd;}?> value="true"><label for="hairdresser"><?php echo $lang['HAIRDRESSER_ICON']; ?></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="express" name="express" <?php if(isset($exp)) {echo $exp;}?> value="true"><label for="express"><?php echo $lang['EXPRESS_ICON']; ?></label>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="includes/captcha.php">
    <input type="text" name="captcha_code" required>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['CONTACT_SEND']; ?>">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: ID should be unique. `id="form1-first-name"` and in a second loop `form2-*` would help

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan even with unique id's, when i click the label on the bottom form it jumps up to the first form :/